# Spring JSP, one tag inside another

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I want to put value of `<s:message code="active.from" />` into `pattern` parameter of another tag like this:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${campaignPerDay[0].date}" 
     pattern="<s:message code="active.from" />" 
/>
```

However it ends with

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/active.jsp(200,106) equal symbol expected
```

I tried some backslashing variations, but it does not help.

Comment: Can you put the full stack trace and specify which line it is referencing?

Answer (score 1):

I solve it with following (however I do not know, if it is the best solution) :

```
<c:set var="dateformat" scope="page"><s:message code="general.dateformat" /></c:set>
<fmt:formatDate value="${campaignsPerDay[0].date}" pattern="${dateformat}" />
```